# How to access anchor tag followed by an ul element?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to access the anchor tags followed by ul elements only. I am using SCSS.

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <a href="#">Menu link 1</a>
  <ul><!--more code here --></ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#">Menu link 2</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#">Menu link 2</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#">Menu link 1</a>
  <ul><!--more code here --></ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please check out this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1817801/4742088). You cannot target a previous sibling using CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options for that:

1. Using a double selector such `:not(:last-child)` increases a bit
   performance degradation. So you should better put your generic CSS
   for the case in which `<a>` is followed by `<ul>` and then use
   `a:only-child` to select and format the other case.
2. Or you can put `<ul>` before `<a>`, then use Flexbox to change the order in the following way:

```css
.parent, .parent ul{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.parent > li {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
}
.parent ul {
  order: 2;
}
ul + a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="parent">
 <li>
  <ul><li>dummy list item</li></ul>
  <a href="#">Menu link 1</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#">Menu link 2</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#">Menu link 2</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#">Menu link 1</a>
  <ul><!--more code here --></ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Css only has backwards looking selectors, so it is not possible to do what your want. But there is an alternative solution that resembles your behavior closely, the `last-child` selector

In your case, you need to combine this with the `:not()` selector.

You will get:

```css
a:not(:last-child) {
    background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>
  <a href="#">Menu link 1</a>
  <ul><!--more code here --></ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#">Menu link 2</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#">Menu link 2</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#">Menu link 1</a>
  <ul><!--more code here --></ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried this and I got the one of anchor tags selected. However, not all of them. Maybe I am doing something. I just want to select the anchor tag followed by an ul element to add a :after pseudo class to it and add a arrow image as background. I dont want that image on anchor that are not followed by an ul element. Maybe there is another way to accomplish this with CSS or jQuery?

Comment: I updated the post, when I use the css rule, I get both the first and last entry, as those both have the `ul` element